# How can I write this equation in latex?

Tags: equations

in this image, how can I write this, the dots befor the number of equation, I mean how can write the second parts of equation, also the dots in number of equation.
[image]

Comment: Welcome. // For a start, apply this chapter: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics . See also the Related links to the right.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Should the weird dots appear only for one particular equation or for all equations in the document?

Comment: Use the free version of [Mathpix](https://mathpix.com/) for this kind of problems.

Comment: Thanks @projetmbc I didn't know Mathpix

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

(Note the use of `\int\limits_a^{\alpha}` in row 1 -- thanks, @SUTerliakov, for suggesting this! -- and of `{\textstyle\int_a{\alpha}` in row 2.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath}    % for 'alignat' env. and '\tag*' macro
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
Q(\alpha) &= w(\alpha)+\gamma \int\limits_a^{\alpha}\! 
             Y(\alpha,\tau) Q(\tau)\,d\tau
          & \qquad
          & b_1\le \alpha \le b_2 
          \refstepcounter{equation} % increment the 'equation' counter
          \tag*{\dots\ (\theequation)\hphantom{a}}\\
-w(\alpha)&= \gamma {\textstyle\int_a^{\alpha}}\,
             Y(\alpha,\tau) Q(\tau)\,d\tau
          &
          & b_1\le \alpha \le b_2  
          \tag*{\dots\ (\theequation a)}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi :-). The OP want also the dots in number of equation. I think to enumitem package.

Comment: @Sebastiano - Thanks for pointing out this extra requirement. I've updated my answer to include the dots.

Comment: You're always WELCOME.

Comment: `\int\limits_a^\alpha` would match the topmost equation typesetting closer: the limits are shown below and above the integral sign, not near it.

Comment: @SUTerliakov - Thanks for this suggestion! I've incorporated it in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Please try with:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
.... \tag*{\ldots(1)}\\
.... \tag*{\ldots(1a)}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I'd copy your code, it won't compile, as important statements are missing. Please complete.

Comment: @MS-SPO I have completed the MWE.

Comment: @Sebastiano - To get the alignment of the equation "numbers" to mimic the OP's screenshot, consider changing `\tag*{\ldots(1)}` to `\tag*{\ldots(1)\hphantom{a}}`. :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano Much thanks for your kindful edit, hats off

Comment: @Mico Thanks for your notification

Comment: @GowriSaro You're welcome :-)